# Getting text from hidden elements using selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm using selenium in python to webscrape information from a website, but I'm running into a problem, that after I click on the website to get more rows from a table, the rows that appear have a `hidden-xs hidden-sm` and I can't seem to find a way to get those elements. My code is below. Is there any way you can help me?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import pandas as pd


flight_Code=[]
Date=[]
Departure=[]
Arrival=[]
aircraft_code=[]

Code=["ph-bfy"]

headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

chrome_path= "C:/Users/hugol/Documents/chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options=Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument({'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'})
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")


driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, options=chrome_options)

url="https://www.flightradar24.com/"
driver.get(url)

login_button=WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'premiumOverlay')))
login_button.click()

username=WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'fr24_SignInEmail')))
username.send_keys(*******)
password=WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'fr24_SignInPassword')))
password.send_keys(*******)

login_button=WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'fr24_SignIn')))
login_button.click()

time.sleep(2)

for i in Code:
    new_url="https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/"+i
    driver.get(new_url)

    more_button=WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'btn-load-earlier-flights')))
    more_button.click()

    # WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'tbl-datatable')))

    for row in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("data-row"):
        try:
            flight_code=row.find_element_by_class_name("fbold").text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            flight_code=''

        try:
            flight_date=row.find_element_by_class_name("row").text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            flight_date=''

        try:
            flight_departure=row.find_elements_by_class_name("details")[4].text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            flight_departure=''
        try:
            flight_arrival=row.find_elements_by_class_name("details")[3].text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            flight_arrival=''

        flight_Code.append(flight_code)
        Date.append(flight_date)
        Departure.append(flight_departure)
        Arrival.append(flight_arrival)
        aircraft_code.append(i)

df=pd.DataFrame({'Code': flight_Code,'Date': Date, 'Departure': Departure, 'Arrival': Arrival, 'Aircraft':aircraft_code})
```

And the website html looks like this:

[image]

Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `element.text` use `element.get_attribute("textContent")`

```
flight_code=row.find_element_by_class_name("fbold").get_attribute("textContent")
```

**Update**:

After click on more button you need to wait for element to be visible.Use Explicit wait.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".data-row")))
```

Comment: that doesn't work because the code is not recognizing the ```<tr class=data-row``` after I click the `more_button`, meaning that it doesn´t get the new 100 flights

Comment: Once you click on more_button just wait for element to load.Use some explicit wait.I have don't have account to login the application else would have check what is happened?

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue, I didn't think of it. I have to wait until everything is loaded. If you can just edit your answer to include the explicit waits solution I will accept the answer.