# Cannot get text from found list though text exists

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, href

I am trying to scrape reference texts from this: [paper](https://doi.org/10.3847/1538-4357/abb3c9)

When I go to the site, the references section does not show up. To see them, I should either click "References" or "+Show References". I am trying to find references link and click it.

Here is my code:

```
browser.get('https://doi.org/10.3847/1538-4357/abb3c9')



refCheck = ["references", "cited literature", "literature cited", "refs"]

for h in range(0, len(browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@href]'))):
    
    textSearch = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@href]')[h].text
    href = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@href]')[h].get_attribute("href")
    
    if (textSearch.lower() in refCheck) & (len(href) > 0):
        
        browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@href]')[h].get_attribute("href")
        
        print(h)
        print(textSearch)
        print(href)
        
        break



browser.get(href)



attrList = []
refCheck = ["references", "cited literature", "literature cited", "refs"]
tags = ["ol","ul"]

for t in tags:

    if len(browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, t)) > 0:

        for i in range(0, len(browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, t))):

            for attr in browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, t)[i].get_property('attributes'):

                for rc in refCheck:

                    if (rc in attr['name'].lower()) | (rc in attr['value'].lower()):
                        
                        attrList.append(t)
                        attrList.append(i)
                        attrList.append(attr['name'])
                        attrList.append(attr['value'])
                        
                        print(attr['name'])
                        print(attr['value'])
                        print(len(browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, t)[i].find_elements(By.XPATH,'./li')))
                        
                if len(attrList) > 0:
                    break
            if len(attrList) > 0:
                break
        if len(attrList) > 0:
            break

cnt = 0
for f in browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, t)[i].find_elements(By.XPATH, './li'):
    print(f.text)
    if len(f.text) > 0:
        refList.append(f.text)
        cnt += 1
        print(cnt)
```

However, the returned text is always empty.

PS. By the way, I have tried to click href I reached instead of browser.get(href), however it does not work as well. When I tried to get the hyperlink through get_attributes("href"), it always returned a string so could not click.

How should I get that text?

**EDIT:**

Found the answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61096491/getting-text-from-hidden-elements-using-selenium-python)

Using get_attribute("textContent") solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternatively `crossref.org` `API` if you search by `DOI` it will give you a JSON response that contains 'reference'. You can play with the json however you want.

```
import requests

def get_ref(doi):
    url = f'https://api.crossref.org/works/{doi}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        response = response.json()
        return response['message']['reference']
    return None

doi = 'doi.org/10.3847/1538-4357/abb3c9'
get_ref_count(doi)
```