# Extract text from href inside table data with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have a table like this:

```
<table style="display: none;">
  <tr>
    <td class='title'>
      <a href='/my/website.html'>This is some text</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to pull "This is some text". But all I can pull is the link.
Here's my code:

```
title = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[@class='title']//a[@href]")

for element in title:
    element_list.append([element.get_attribute("href"), element.text])
```

The results are a list that contains the links, but no text. Where am I going wrong?

Is there an easy way to see what attributes a selenium object has?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting text from hidden elements using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61096491/getting-text-from-hidden-elements-using-selenium-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it right... kinda. The problem is that the TABLE is invisible, according to the HTML you posted, so `.text` won't work.

```
<table style="display: none;">
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can use `.get_attribute()` to grab the text. Change your script to the below.

```
for element in title:
    element_list.append([element.get_attribute("href"), element.get_attribute("innerHTML"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution while this question was in the "Staging Ground": [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/37024/how-do-i-get-the-text-of-a-hyperlink-not-the-actual-link-using-selenium-and-py).
.text does not pull the text from an href. To do that I had to switch to .get_attribute('text').

So my code:

```
title = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[@class='title']//a[@href]")
for element in title:
    element_list.append([element.get_attribute("href"), element.text])
```

Became

```
title = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[@class='title']//a[@href]")
for element in title:
    element_list.append([element.get_attribute("href"), element.get_attribute('text')])
```